# PDO 'UPDATE' Statement with parameters does not work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sql-update

I have this PDO statement that doesn't update my database and doesn't return any error:

```
// $database = initialized PDO instance
$status = 'processing';
$submission_id = 213;

$sql  = "UPDATE `submission` 
  SET `status`=':status' 
  WHERE `id`=':submission_id'";

$query = $database->prepare($sql);
$result = $query->execute(array(
  ':status' => $status, 
  ':submission_id' => $submission_id
));

var_dump($result);            // true
var_dump($query->rowCount()); // 0
$database->errorCode();       // 0000
$database->errorInfo();       // [0]=> string(5) "00000" [1]=> NULL [2]=> NULL
```

If I remove parameters from $sql it works:

```
$sql2 = "UPDATE `submission` SET `status`='processing' WHERE `id`='214'";
```

all results are the same except `$query->rowCount()` which returns 1 this time and the database is updated. I use the same PDO object for other insert and select operations and it works well.

Why the first parametized query doesn't work?

Comment: Wrap off quotes from your first query placeholder!!

Comment: Thanks all! At first I had no quotes but experienced some other error, so then I've added them as an attempt to fix it, removed the other error and that's how I got here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not quote parameters:

```
$sql  = "UPDATE `submission` 
  SET `status`=:status 
  WHERE `id`=:submission_id";
```

Answer (score 1):

Stop using double quotes

```
$status = 'processing';
$submission_id = 213;

$sql  = "UPDATE `submission` 
  SET `status`=:status 
  WHERE `id`=:submission_id";

$query = $database->prepare($sql);
$result = $query->execute(array(
  ':status' => $status, 
  ':submission_id' => $submission_id
));
```

Answer (score 1):

As per  [PDO statement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

> The parameters to prepared statements don't need to be quoted; the
>   driver automatically handles this.

SO wrap off quotes from placeholder in your query

```
$sql  = "UPDATE `submission` 
SET `status`=:status
WHERE `id`=:submission_id";
```